# Create a callable object with arguments already supplied in Python

Tags: python, function, callable-object

Essentially I am trying to pass arguments to a function but defer the execution that function until later. I don't want to delay by some amount of time or I would just `sleep`. Here's the usage I'm going for

```
import requests

def test_for_active_server(server_address):
    response = requests.get(server_address)

try_n_times(func, expected_error, n_iterations):
    for i in range(n_iterations):
        try:
            func()
            break
        except expected_error:
            continue
    else:
        return False
    return True

try_n_times(
    create_callable(test_for_active_server("http://localhost/"),  
    requests.ConnectionError, 10)
```

The problem here of course is that when I call `test_for_active_server("http://localhost/")` it will just run right away so the argument to `create_callable` will just be `None`. I believe I could do this with something like

```
def create_callable(func, func_args: List[str], func_kwargs: Dict[str, str], *args):
    def func_runner():
        func(*args, *func_args, **func_kwargs)
    return func_runner
```

and then use it as

```
create_callable(test_for_active_server, "http://localhost")
```

But this is rather awkward. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

You can supply all the arguments, so you can do something like:

```python
obj = functools.partial(test_for_active_server, server_address="http://localhost/")
# ...do other things...
obj()
```

Comment: you can also use `lambda`.

Comment: Well, nice I guess that the `create_callable` idea that I had is already included for you. Sad that this is the way to do this.